# Arc length of the curve y=ln(x)

Tags: arc-length

Q: Find the arc length of the curve $y=\ln(x)$ where $x$ ranges from $\sqrt{3}$ to $\sqrt{15}$.

I think I am stuck in calculation part.

[image]

[image]

The answer is $2 + \ln(3) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(5)$. But I can't derive that from my last line.

help me, please.

Comment: Review your last two computations. $\sqrt{15}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are values of $x$ and not for $\theta$

Comment: You have to change the limits of the integration as well.

Comment: Does theta range from arctan(sqrt(3)) to arctan(sqrt(15))? The computations are still difficult to me..

Comment: In your last term of the answer, is it really $-\frac{1}{2}\ln 5$?

Comment: Yes. My book says it is 2 + ln(3) - (1/2)*ln(5) units.

Comment: Just for suggestion.  I will suggest you to start with$$F(x)=\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}dx$$

Comment: All your solutions after the substitution $x=\tan\theta$ are all wrong. Why?

Comment: When you make the substitution $x = \tan \theta$ you must recalculate your limits of integration to go with your new variable.  (or convert back to x before applying the limits of integration.

Comment: When x = sqrt(3), theta = arctan(sqrt(3)). And when x = sqrt(15), theta = arctan(sqrt(15)). Are these right?

Comment: $\arctan \sqrt 3 = \frac \pi 3$  not that that is a big deal.  What is more important to know is that $\csc \arctan \sqrt 3 = \frac 2{\sqrt 3}, \sec \arctan \sqrt 3 = 2,$ etc.

Comment: csc (arctan(sqrt(3)) = csc (pi/3) = 1/sin(pi/3) = 1/(sqrt(3)/2) = 2/sqrt(3).         sec (arctan(sqrt(3)) = sec (pi/3) = 1/cos(pi/3) = 1/(1/2) = 2.                                What about sqrt(15)? Give me some hints, please.

Comment: @Kim It seems that your computations are going complicated. An alternate way of doing it is given in my answer below. Try it. We used the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @Kim I will be going out for now and chat me if you have some more questions to raise. God bless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem now is how to evaluate the integral $$\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{15}}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}dx.$$

Let 
$$F(x)=\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}dx.$$
Let $x=\tan\theta$. All your computations after this substitution are all correct.
Note that $$\csc\theta=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$$ $$\cot\theta=\frac{1}{x}$$ and
$$\sec\theta=\sqrt{x^2+1}.$$ 
Hence, we get
$$F(x)=-\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+1}{x} \right)+\sqrt{x^2+1}+C.$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align} 
\int_{\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{15}}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}dx&=F(\sqrt{15})-F(\sqrt{3})\\
&=\left[-\ln\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt{15}}\right)+4+C\right]-\left[-\ln\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+2+C\right]\\
&=\ln\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\ln\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt{15}}\right) +2\\
&=\ln\left[\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}\div\frac{5}{\sqrt{15}}\right]+2\\
&=\ln\left[\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{15}}{5}\right]+2\\
&=\ln\left[\frac{3}{1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}\right]+2\\
&=\ln\left[\frac{3}{1} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right]+2\\
&=\ln\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\right)+2\\
&=\ln 3-\ln\sqrt{5}+2\\
&=\ln 3-\frac{1}{2}(\ln 5)+2.
\end{align}$$